# How can I extend Magento API for sales_order.info

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, xml-rpc

I'm using the Magento APIv1 to get the sales order information.

But now I want to include some extra fields I added to the DB table sales_flat_order.

Searching the web got me some hints where the API could be modified, but I didn't had some real success.
I can find the API description in the file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/api.xml

```
...
<info translate="title" module="sales">
    <title>Retrieve order information</title>
    <acl>sales/order/info</acl>
</info>
 ...
```

But I cannot find the php file where this order information is collected and tied together.
Maybe someone more experienced with Magento can tell me which file is to be edited to add my custom fields.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Similar question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1330/where-do-you-put-modified-wsdl-files-for-the-api-to-override-the-core-definition/1331#1331

It suggests adding the attribute to the wsdl.xml:

```
    <definitions...>
        <types>
            <schema ...>
                <complexType name="catalogProductEntity">
                    <all>
                        <element name="custom_attribute" type="xsd:string"/>
                    </all>
                </complexType>
            </schema>
        </types>
    </definitions>
```